# i want to determine the two-letter combination that occurs most often in my code

Tags: c

i have a file (for example lorem.txt)
so now i have two task ,

1. was to read file and remove space and lines.
2. to determine the two letter combination that occurs most often in my file.

i have done the first part. can anyone tell me what can i do to 2. part? I tried various solutions, but was unable to do it. Let me know, if I can provide anything else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit()

FILE* pInputFile;
int chr = 0;
int main()
{
    FILE* fptr;

    char c;
    char filename[] = "Lorem.txt";
    char *str, *strblank;
   // char str[469], strblank[469];
    int i = 0;
    //int x=500;

    errno_t err;

    if ((err = fopen_s(&pInputFile, "Lorem.txt", "r")) == 0)
    {
        size_t pos = ftell(pInputFile);    // Current position
        fseek(pInputFile, 0, SEEK_END);    // Go to end
        size_t length = ftell(pInputFile); // read the position which is the size
        fseek(pInputFile, pos, SEEK_SET);  // restore original position
        
        //x = length;
        //char str[x], strblank[x];
        printf("%d", length);
        str = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
        strblank = malloc(length * sizeof(char));

        // file exists: don't read a char before the loop or
        // it will be lost

        while ((chr = getc(pInputFile)) != EOF)
        {
           //printf("%c", chr); //This line prints the file lines.
            str[i] = chr;
            i++;
        }

        i= 0;
        printf("%s", str);

        removespace(str, strblank);
        printf("%s", strblank);
        fclose(pInputFile);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file, error %d\n", err);
        // handle the error further if needed
    }
    return 0;
}
int removespace(char aj[500],char mj[500])
{
   
    //char mj[500];
    int i = 0, j = 0, len;

    //printf("\n\nEnter the string: ");
    //gets(aj);

    len = strlen(aj);   // len stores the length of the input string

    while (aj[i] != '\0')    // till string doesn't terminate
    {
        if (aj[i] != ' ' && aj[i] != '\n')  // if the char is not a white space
        {
            /*
                incrementing index j only when
                the char is not space
            */
            mj[j++] = aj[i];
        }
        /*
            i is the index of the actual string and
            is incremented irrespective of the spaces
        */
        i++;
    }
    mj[j] = '\0';
    // printf("\n\nThe string after removing all the spaces is: ");
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider `a` (`0`), `b` (`1`), `c` (`2`), ..., `z` (`25`) the *digits* of numbers in base `26`. Make an array with `26*26` elements all initialized to `0`. Count `"aa"` into `array[0*26 + 0]`, ... `"ck"` into `array[2*26 + 10] /* 'c'*26 + 'k' */`...

Comment: @Bansi - In the string `oh no`, do you consider `hn` a _two-letter combination_?

Comment: you can have a 128*128 2D array which rows indicate first letter and column indicate second letter. then fill that array with iterating on string (0 to len-2) and fill arr like this: arr[ str[i] ][ str[i+1] ]++; then find max in that 2d array.

Comment: @Armali no. example: oh oh no. oh -2, no -1. hn wont be considered as a two lettered combination.

Comment: @dreamcrash how can it be converted to MPI?

Comment: If you don't want combinations from separate words, it's a bad idea to _remove space_, don't you think so?

Comment: @Armali thats another task and this one is another task. both are not related to each other. did you get my point?

Comment: I don't get why you post code for an unrelated task.